# Project Euler 37 Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out why my program won't work for this problem. It is about truncatable primes.

**Original Problem**

The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.

Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.

NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

I think I have the Truncatable part of the program correct:

```
public static boolean isTruncatable(String x) {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, x.length() - i));
            if (!isPrime(num)) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("From right: " + num);
            num = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, x.length()));
            if (!isPrime(num)) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("From left: " + num);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Running that with "3797" as the input prints

```
From right: 3797
From left: 3797
From right: 379
From left: 797
From right: 37
From left: 97
From right: 3
From left: 7
```

**Rest of program**

```
public class Problem37TruncatablePrimes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int counter = 0, sum = 0, i = 10;
        while (counter < 10) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                if (isTruncatable(Integer.toString(i))) {
                    sum += i;
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println((stop - start) + "ms");
    }

    public static boolean isTruncatable(String x) {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(0, x.length() - i));
            if (!isPrime(num)) {
                return false;
            }
            num = Integer.parseInt(x.substring(i, x.length()));
            if (!isPrime(num)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        if (x == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(x); i++) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

It doesn't reach 3797 and prints

```
11
13
17
23
31
37
53
71
73
113
442
```

Thanks for helping.

**Edit:** The problem was that 1 isn't a prime number so thanks to wolfsgang for pointing that out. Also, I wanted it to go to 3797 because the problem said that there are only 11 Truncatable primes and 3797 is one of them.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Other than 442 clearly not being prime, that looks... vaguely reasonable. Why do you think you should reach 3797?

Comment: OK, so... instead of stopping after finding the first 10 (`while (counter < 10) {`), stop after finding the first 11.

Comment: 442 is the sum guys. But you are supposed to have 11 primes not 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers like 11, 13,31, 71, 113 aren't left and right truncatable as 1 isn't a prime number.
You have to change your isPrime() function to include this case.Then only you will have exactly 11 prime numbers till 3797.
Otherwise you will get 11 numbers in the first 1000 numbers itself as tractable, when you run this code. 
Also change

```
(while (counter < 10) {)
```

to

```
(while (counter < 11) {)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is the answer, he just has to change his isPrime function to include this case, as then it will give the exact results.Otherwise in this function he will get 11 truncatable numbers in the first 1000 numbers itself

Comment: But you don't explain that in your answer: you just say "it is wrong". Please expand your answer. Also, the code will only find 10 truncatable numbers.

Comment: Here added more explanation,also I never said "it is wrong", just what to change.

Comment: I was paraphrasing. Don't assume that people follow you when you make a comment about something not working: it might be the case that fixes everything, but if you don't say it, you may just look like you are pointing out "a" bug, not "the" bug.